# Function handleWordPositionColor is not getting called

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am writing code in react native but facing an issue, handleWordPositionColor function I have created but it is not getting called. Console.log statements in the function are not showing output. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
handleWordPositionColor = () => {
    console.log("entered handlePositionColor function")
    let color = this.state.wordPositionColorArray[0];
    console.log("color", color);
    let tempArray = this.state.wordPositionColorArray;
    tempArray.shift();
    console.log("tempArray", tempArray);
    this.setState({
      wordPositionColorArray: tempArray,
      wordPositionColor: color,
    });
  };

return(
<View style={styles.guess_container}>
    {guess.map((guessObj, index) => {
    if (guessObj.letter == " ") {
        console.log("entered black space")
        this.handleWordPositionColor;
    }
    return (
        <View key={index}>
            <View style={styles.letter_container}>
                {this.guessedLetterButton(guessObj.letter, index)}
                {guessObj.letter != " " && (
                 <View
                   style={[
                   styles.underline,
                   { backgroundColor: this.state.wordPositionColor },
                    ]}
                  ></View>
                 )}
              </View>
          </View>
              );
            })}
</View>
);
```

Comment: `this.handleWordPositionColor();`

Comment: that's not the right way, I am using setState in my function. Function will call itself again and again.

Comment: Here, you write it as a reference to that function, not actually calling this.handleWordPositionColor, if want to call then, writes as this.handleWordPositionColor() and it's called multiple time reason behind that map iterate and condition getting true it will call

Comment: @MeetMajevadiya how to resolve this?

Comment: can make it on code sandbox so I can get hall idea behind that

Comment: @MeetMajevadiya sure. But how to do that?